# How to add p values into grouped charts in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value, ggpubr, violin-plot

When I want to add p values into my plots:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

 stat.test3 <- MP %>%
    group_by(TBI) %>%
    wilcox_test(age ~ mp_1) %>%
    adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni") %>%
    add_significance("p.adj")%>%
  mutate(y.position = 35)

 C2<-  ggplot(data=MP, aes(x=TBI, y=age, fill=mp_1))+
    geom_violin()+
    geom_boxplot(width=.2, fatten=NULL, position = position_dodge(0.9))+
    stat_summary(fun="median", geom="point", position = position_dodge(0.9))+
    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", geom = "errorbar", width=.1, position = position_dodge(0.9))+
      scale_fill_brewer(name="Mind-pop", palette = "Accent")

  C2+ stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test3, xmin = "TBI",xmax = NULL)
```

it gives me this error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'mp_1' not found
> This error is shown after adding stat_pvalue to the object.
> How should I fix it?

Comment: could you please share with us a sample of your data? (`dput(MP, 10)`)

Comment: age 55 54 56 60 55 53 61 56 58 58 56 58 58 58 59 57 56 60 57 58 61 60
TBI TBI TBI TBI TBI TBI TBI TBI TBI TBI TBI TBI HC HC HC HC HC HC HC HC HC HC HC
mp_1 Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes No Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes No Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `ggpubr` so can't say I understand the underlying issue but it seems like `color=mp_1` instead of `fill=mp_1` might fix your issue. This is in the following line:

`C2 <- ggplot(data=MP, aes(x=TBI, y=age, color=mp_1))`.

The full code is below. I've also changed `y.position` so that the significance is at the top of the plot.

```
MP <- structure(list(age = c(55L, 54L, 56L, 60L, 55L, 53L, 61L, 56L, 
                             58L, 58L, 56L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 57L, 56L, 60L, 57L, 58L, 61L, 
                             60L),
                     mp_1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
                     TBI = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("HC", 
                "TBI"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))

library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
    
stat.test3 <- MP %>%
  group_by(TBI) %>%
  wilcox_test(age ~ mp_1) %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni") %>%
  add_significance("p.adj") %>%
  mutate(y.position = 61.5)

C2 <-  ggplot(data=MP, aes(x=TBI, y=age, color=mp_1))+
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot(width=.2, fatten=NULL, position = position_dodge(0.9))+
 stat_summary(fun="median", geom="point", position = position_dodge(0.9))+
 stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", geom = "errorbar", width=.1, position = position_dodge(0.9))+
 scale_fill_brewer(name="Mind-pop", palette = "Accent")

C2 + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test3, xmin = "TBI",xmax = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time. I want to have grouped violin plots and because of that I used fill.

Comment: Would `ggviolin` address what you're trying to achieve? As in `ggviolin(data=MP, "TBI", "age",  fill = "mp_1", add = "boxplot") + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test3, xmin = "TBI",xmax = NULL)`